# Sort array in Czech, localeCompare

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting

I have problem sorting an array with Czech names. It works ok for the normal characters but not for the special ones. 'Sb', 'St', 'Šk' ; the special Š should be after the other two words, but it end it up in different order. Here is a simple code.

```
var tmpArr = ['Sb', 'BE', 'De', 'CS', 'Au', 'Šk', 'De', 'St', 'Ci', 'št'];

function mySort(s1, s2) {
return s1.localeCompare(s2 ,'cz', {sensitivity: "variant"});
}

var sorted = tmpArr.sort(mySort);

console.log(tmpArr);

for(var i in sorted){
console.log(sorted[i]);
}
```

This should be also working in all browsers.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Dobrý Den,

as this states

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare

advanced options for locale compare are not implemented in common browsers.

If you need this only for Chech language maybe it would be best idea to implement your own string comparison using characters map:

```
var charMapL = " 0123456789aábcčdďeéěfghiíjklmnňoópqrřsštťuúůvwxyýzž";
var charMapU = " 0123456789AÁBCČDĎEÉĚFGHIÍJKLMNŇOÓPQRŘSŠTŤUÚŮVWXYÝZŽ";
var charsOrder = {};
for(var i in charMapL.split('')) {
    charsOrder[charMapL[i]] = parseInt(i);
    charsOrder[charMapU[i]] = parseInt(i);
}

function mySort(s1, s2) {
    var idx = 0;
    while ( (idx < s1.length) && (idx < s2.length) && (charsOrder[s1[idx]] == charsOrder[s2[idx]])) {
        idx ++;
    }
    if ((idx == s1.length) && (idx == s2.length)) return 0;
    if (idx == s1.length) return 1;
    if (idx == s2.length) return -1;
    return charsOrder[s1[idx]] > charsOrder[s2[idx]] ? 1 : (charsOrder[s1[idx]] < charsOrder[s2[idx]] ? -1 : 0);
}

console.log(tmpArr);
tmpArr.sort();
console.log(tmpArr);
tmpArr.sort(mySort);
console.log(tmpArr);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GNNBc/1/

Comment: This will return `1` for two equal strings. `0` is never actually returned.

Comment: @JanDvorak thanks for noticing, fixed. But can you give an example case for witch this is a problem? What is the difference if i will say s1 is larger than s2 if they are equal? sorting would not be affected. or does this make a difference in MergeSort efficiency?

Comment: @sla55er sorting strings with numbers in it was probably not working correctly coz you would have to add digits to your characters map. this function can be also improved treating every non alpha-numeric character somehow.